# HtmlAgilitypack enumerate all classes

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, enums

I have been dealing with html a lot in general and always used `Regex` to get my results. Every time I look for help though, everyone recommends to use HTML parsers, such as HTMLAgilitypack.

I just tried it and man, it is too much for me at the moment.
This is how I tried to enumerate the spans of the html code

```
private static string _InetReadEx(string sUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = website.Load(sUrl);

            var allElementsWithClassFloat = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'pid')]");
            for (int i = 0; i < allElementsWithClassFloat.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText);
            }

            return aRet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and I am getting the error `Expression must evaluate to a node-set`

I have uploaded the HTML file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/test_41) because it was too big to add it on the post
I need to enumerate all the classes that contain "pid".

Comment: You can shorten the code by removing `HttpWebRequest` since HtmlAgilityPack can load html files. If you want to get all the tags with the `div` name having `class` attr equal to `pid`, use `"//div[@class='pid']"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception thrown.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the tip though. I modified the method. Hope did it the right way.

Comment: That is because  the file does not contain any `div` tags whose `class` attribute value contains `pid`. Please formulate what you need to extract from that file. Also, to avoid using `try..catch` and these exceptions, you should check if the object is not null. `var allElementsWithClassFloat = htmlDoc.DocumentNode....` and then `if (allElementsWithClassFloat != null) { /*Process*/ }`

Comment: I had it like that before but I need exception thrown for testing. That's why I changed it.
In the file you will find this: "<td class="pid-1-last">1.0972</td>"
And I want to find everything that contains "pid" in it.

Comment: Then you need `"//*[contains(@class,'pid')]"`. Also, if you do not need empty values, do not forget to add `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText))` and if you do not need dupes, you may also check `if (!aRet.Contains(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
private static List<string> _InetReadEx(string sUrl)    // Returns string list
{
    var aRet = new List<string>();                      // string list var
    try
    {
        var website = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();    // Init the object
        var htmlDoc = website.Load(sUrl);               // Load doc from URL

        var allElementsWithClassFloat = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'pid')]"); // Get all nodes with class value containing pid
        if (allElementsWithClassFloat != null)          // If nodes found
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allElementsWithClassFloat.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText) && // if not blank/null
                    !aRet.Contains(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText)) // if not already present
                {
                    aRet.Add(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText);  // Add to result
                    Console.WriteLine(allElementsWithClassFloat[i].InnerText); // Demo line
                }
            }
        }
        return aRet;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The XPath is `//*[contains(@class,'pid')]`:

- `//*` - get all element nodes that...
- `[contains(` - contain...
- `@class,'pid'` - `pid` substring inside the `class` attribute value
- `)]` - end of the `contains` condition

Comment: Very well explained. Big thanks for the help. I have a question though. You suggested to remove HttpWebRequest because HtmlAgilityPack can do what I wanted to. I did indeed removed it. However I will have an infinity loop where I will be getting the informations in miliseconds. Is it better to use HtmlAgilityPack  to direct link of have a HTTP connection, request the html page every hounderds miliseconds and then parse it with HtmlAgilityPack ?

Comment: I did not test the performance of loading multiple documents consecutively with HAP. I think it should not matter much since the underlying file fetching relies on the same HttpWebRequest class. You may pass headers, set encoding, etc., same way you'd use HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the comma (`,`) and the right bracket (`)`) in your XPath? Looks wrong to me.

Should be `"//div[@class='pid']"`, although that's for an exact match. If you want to select any elements that contain '*pid*' anywhere in the class attribute value, you can use `"//div[contains(@class,'pid')]"`

Stick with HtmlAgilityPack - I've used it a lot because most HTML on the web is garbage, and not even valid XML!

Comment: Actually, you should pad the class with spaces and search for that in order to avoid finding partial matches... `class="stupid"` would also match now. E.g. `//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' pid ')]`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error thrown

Comment: On which line?!  Which object is null?!
You're going to have to help yourself at some point.